# When did Matt and Trey stop intentionally censoring South Park with bleeps?

Tags: dialogue, south-park, censorship

I am aware Matt and Trey intentionally censored South Park, but for some time, [southparkstudios.com](http://www.southparkstudios.com/) has been offering uncensored versions of the show about a week or two after airing on TV. And, according to the [South Park Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Park), South Park airs uncensored in some places.

When did Matt and Trey stop intentionally censoring South Park with bleeps?

Comment: Did they ever censor it ? I don't recall any censoring apart from the prophet's double episode, part 2.

Comment: @Eregrith They did, also, famously Cartman Get's an Anal Probe: Kyle `You like to _____ and sh___ and _____ and _____ and _____ and _____!` Stan `Hey Wendy, what's a _____?` I noticed there are no alternative "uncensored" audio tracks on the earlier season's DVDs either...I get bleeps

Comment: Clarification: Do you mean the whole show uncensored in general, as in instances like The Profit or just mostly language censor?

Comment: I'm talking profanity so language only. I just realized there are instances they don't even bleep, the characters lips move, and the transcripts contain the word(s).

Comment: I don't understand humancentipad but when I saw it on the south park web it's UNCENSORED but I think the tv version is censored

Comment: @TryTryAgain that particular example is a lot funnier if you don't know what was said. That's Kenny's whole shtick after all (apart from being killed).

Comment: There was the episode after some ruling or change that meant that “sh/t” was allowed on extended cable channels in the US after 8:00 or 9:00pm. That episode had a counter in the corner that showed the number of times it was said in the episode. So that’s at least one clear change in how cursing was handled in South Park.

Answer (score 9):

Matt and Trey never censored South Park. The networks airing their show do the censoring as required by their broadcast licenses. A broadcast license is relative to the country that issues it. An Americian station's license is not govern by licenses required in Canada, even if their air waves cross the border.

So you can watch an episode in Canada from the US and see content/language that you might not see on a Canadian channel, and vice versa.

You can see these shows aired without censorship when the broadcast uses data encryption to deliver the content. This might include networks like The Movie Network (TMN) and Comedy Central's subscription channels.

Channels/air waves that employ encryption are not governed by public airwaves standards of their licenses, because the delivery is to targeted subscribers who pay to decrypt the signal.

So on those channels you can see porn, hear all language, etc, etc.

Comedy Central is a subscription channel delivered privately to satellite/cable viewers who pay for the subscription. They likely switched over to encryption after digital TV became standard.

Comment: I'm talking about their actual non-broadcast releases, their DVD releases etc, in which they do actually censor. I understand that networks choose to censor their broadcast, but there are episodes Matt and Trey censor on purpose and as far as I can tell, they only started releasing uncensored versions around Season 9. Everything before that was bleeped or left blank, even though the transcript shows the profane content.

Answer (score 6):

You may still see recent episodes with bleeps. Matt and Trey explained in an interview that sometimes they use real children to make the  voice acting. When this happens the script does not have actual curse words but stuff like:

- Shat!
- Frog!
- Mother Froster!

:) .  And then the bleep is added to the show because the character should actually curse.

In the last two seasons however Matt and Trey seem to do all the voices so I don't think it has happened since

Comment: Which characters are voiced by real children?

Comment: @ToddWilcox Ike, Filmore, and the other small kids